# adding an horizontal line in chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am generating a chart out of an table in.

I would like to have an horizontal line in the chart. I call this as an setpoint and the data is available in column E of my table.

also, I would like to change m axis scale. I would like to have axis value from 0 - 10 with percentage sign.

Any lead would be helpful. I have tried till this with my chart.

```
Sub chartRedResultPer()
Dim Rng, rng1, rng2  As Range
Dim cht1 As Object
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A53")
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D53")
Set Rng = Union(rng1, rng2)
Set Sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=320, _
    Width:=600, _
    Top:=70, _
    Height:=250)
Sh.Select
Set cht1 = ActiveChart
With cht1
.SetSourceData Source:=Rng
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
cht1.Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
cht1.SeriesCollection(1).delete
End With
cht1.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Red "
cht1.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
cht1.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
cht1.HasTitle = True
cht1.ChartTitle.Text = "Result 2017"
End Sub
```

Comment: The best explanation you'll find for any of your Excel charting questions is to visit [Jon Peltier's site](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/). [Here's the answer](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineHorzSeries.html) you're looking for.

Comment: @PeterT I don't find any code to help em

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another range

```
Dim rng3 as Range
Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E53")

With cht1.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "SetPoint"
    .Values = rng3
    .Type = xlLine
    .MarkerStyle = None
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With

With cht1.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = 10
        .MinimumScale = 0
End With
```

Comment: H the code is helpful, Thank you, can you tell me how I can format the y/axis with scale 0-10 with percentage ?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: I am using the 0.0% number format to show them in percentage. but this then changing my value 10 In my axis to 1000%. is there a way, I can just add % to my axis

Comment: Then show the maximum as 1, .1 or state the maximum in percentage.  Mathematically equivalent.

Comment: @Jenny - Use a custom number format of `0.0"%"` Putting the percent sign in quotes appends it to the labels without changing the values to percentages.

Answer (score 1):

The code would be like this.

```
Sub ColumnChart()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2   As Range, rng3 As Range
    Dim cht1 As Chart, Sh As ChartObject

    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A53")
    Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D53")
    Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("e2:e53")

    Set Sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=320, _
        Width:=600, _
        Top:=70, _
        Height:=250)

    Set cht1 = Sh.Chart

    With cht1
        n = .SeriesCollection.Count
        If n > 0 Then
            For j = n To 1 Step -1
                .SeriesCollection(j).Delete
            Next j
        End If
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionRight
        With .ChartTitle
            .Characters.Text = "Result 2017"
            .Characters.Font.Size = 12
        End With

            i = i + 1
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With .SeriesCollection(i)
                .Name = "Red "
                .XValues = rng1
                .Values = rng2
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .ApplyDataLabels
            End With
            With .SeriesCollection(i).DataLabels
                .ShowValue = True

                .Font.Size = 7
            End With

            i = i + 1
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With .SeriesCollection(i)
                .Name = "Pecent "
                .XValues = rng1
                .Values = rng3
                .AxisGroup = 2
                .ChartType = xlLine
                .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End With


            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Red "
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,###"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "x Axes"

    End With


End Sub
```